# 301 Redirect a domain to new domain and add extra subdirectory to the existing path

Tags: htaccess, apache

i want to redirect my old domain to new domain `x.com - y.com`
and also, my old domain x.com currently doesn't have sub directory in url

```
ex: x.com/news-today
```

for my new domain y.com having sub directory in url

```
ex: y.com/news/news-today
```

i want to redirect my old domain x.com with new sub directory "/news" adding in it

```
x.com/news-today --> y.com/news/news-today
```

Comment: Do the old and new domain point to the same place? Or different servers?

Answer (score 1):

The answer could be simple or complex, depending on your situation. First of all, I am going to assume that the content for `x.com` is hosted separately from `y.com` and that you can modify the `.htaccess`.

In the `.htaccess` for `x.com`

```
Redirect /news-today https://www.y.com/news/news-today
```

However, I'm guessing that isn't the only URL that you want to redirect. If there's only a few, you could use a Redirect for each one, but you'll likely need a wildcard RewriteRule. This answer again depends on your situation. If you have a consistent format of the example where you have hyphenated key words, and the directory being redirected to is the first key word, then try this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)-(.*)$ https://www.y.com/$1/$1-$2 [R=301,L]
```

If both domain names point to the same content and the same `.htaccess` will be applied whether the visitor is at x or y, you'll need to use conditions such as:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^x\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.x\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*?)-(.*)$ https://www.y.com/$1/$1-$2 [R=301,L]
```

Or an <If> Directive

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} =~ /x\.com$/">
 RewriteRule .*/(.*?)-(.*)$ https://www.y.com/$1/$1-$2 [R=301,L]
</If>
```